# Is a resistor required to power a LED strip with a 9V battery?

Tags: led, batteries, resistors, resistance, led-strip

I have a 7020 white light LED strip, which includes a resistor on each module as you can see:
[image]

I would like to power a little strip of five of these modules with a 9 V battery, but I wonder :

1- Do I **need** to put a resistor beetween the battery and the strip (so the leds do not catch fire or early die, or anything inappropriate)?

2- If I do, how many ohms do it needs to be?

**EDIT :**
The question is not about the intensity of the light that the LEDs can emit, nor about how long the battery will operate.

As the strip comes prewired and includes a resistor on each module, I suppose that this is not required, but I read everywhere that lighting a single LED requires a resistor upfront, and I can't find anything about how this applies or not to LED strips.

Comment: If it's the type with builtin resistors, then no, you don't. Also notice that it says 12V and they might not be very bright, or maybe won't work at all, with 9V.

Comment: No, and in addition the LEDs will be very dim, if they light at all on 9V.

Comment: I have no idea why you want to use a low capacity 9V battery with a 12V LEDstrip, but it won't work very bright or very long You have 2 choices, short out 1 LED , short out the resistor.

Comment: @immibis,Jack Creasey,Tony EE rocketscientist With a 9V battery without added resistor, they light up, and they are really bright. Not as much than with a 12V power, but they are very bright. With a resistor, of course, they are less bright, reason why I ask if I need to put it.

Comment: @Tony EE rocketscientist I want to do this because 9V battery light them up quite well, and it is small, light and autonomous (not like a huge 12V battery, or a wall plug).

Comment: Do you want 3 dimmer or 2 brighter?  so short the R or 1 LED. Those are your simple choices.

Comment: @Tony EE rocketscientist As described, I want 15 (5x3) dimmer leds (not so dim because they are strong enough so I can't stand looking at them with naked eyes powered with the 9V battery). In that configuration, how do you short 1 led or 1 resistor ? By the way, the question was not if I have to short somes pieces of the strips, but if I had to add an entry resistor, so the leds do not catch fire or early die, or anything inappropriate.

Comment: No worries.  But do as I said. Get AWG 30 wire or WW wire and carefully solder it to bridge the end terminals of the resistor. But it will dim quickly with battery < 9V  so 2 LEDs shorting 1 LED is better or short with a current limiting R like 3V/20mA=150 Ohms -39 Ohms = 120 OHms across 1 LED.  No other simple choices.except value of R and operating time vs brightness.  Solder in 3 seconds or leave it. Tack it on with short leads.  There are far better ways to make a LED light.

Comment: @Tony EE rocketscientist Thank you for your try, but the purpose of the question is not about how intense the light will be nor how long the battery will last. Nor shorting anything on these strips. Just, do I need to put a resistance beetween the battery and the strip, among other things to prevent them to die or catch fire, ... , and if yes, how many ohms should it be ? As the strip comes prewired and includes a resistor on each module, I originaly suppose that this isn't required, but I read everywhere that lighting just a LED requires a resistor upfront, but I find nothing about LED strips

Comment: If the strip is designed to operate on 12 volts (presumablly without any external current limiting) it will certainly operate on 9 volts without any external current limiting.  But you could add a resistor if you want to dim the LEDs.

Comment: @PeterBennett I don't want to dim the LEDs, I wonder if I need a resistor at the entry of the circuit to protect them (or protect the battery ?) from failure / catching fire / ...

Comment: @Oliver  Your assumptions are wrong. It won't catch fire. But shorting out the battery will make it bulge and get hot and some may result in toxic fumes perhaps.  The issues are how long will the battery last before the 9V drops below 3 LED threshold of 8.5V or so when dim. Because it will use all the battery capacity with 2 LEDs but then why a cheap 9V battery when if you are handy soldering you can rewire it to run off 3 LEDs in parallel and 3.6 V Li-Ion or a few other options not just what R-value?

Comment: Again the simplest solution is short out the resistor but then dims quickly in an hour as Vbat drops below 9V

Answer (score 3):

The typical 12V strip has a voltage range of 10 to 14 volts. Less than 10 and they barely light. The leds alone  have a forward voltage of 3.6V at their typical nominal forward current, so you add in the voltage drop across the resistor, and 9V won't cut it.

You could short out the resistor as suggested and connect the 9V battery. It's internal equivalent series resistance and the lower voltage will light the leds at less than normal brightness. Unfortunately a 9V battery has low capacity and won't last long. Slightly better, you can short 1 led, and add a resistor in series. The resistor should be (Vs - Vf) / If = R1 + R2, where r1 is the existing resistor, vs is voltage source 9V, and Vf is 3.6 times 2 for 2 leds. If may be 0.06 A or 60mA for those leds. This would last a little longer.

If you want 5 of these in parallel, your 9V battery ain't going to last half an hour...

Instead, get 5V led strips, and a usb power bank. Rechargeable, no resistors needed. Just an old usb cable.

Comment: When you suggest to short one led, do you mean one on each of the 5 modules ? Also, on your formula, what is If ? Is [(9-(3.6*2)) / If]  -39ohms is the good calculation ?

Comment: Why are you making a MIckey Mouse flashlight?

Comment: @Oliver yes one per module. And If is the forward current at the forward voltage. I'm assuming it's going to be like 60 mA.

Comment: Current white lighting LEDs typically have a Vf of 2.8V and exceed 3V only at currents approaching 1 Amp.  9V will cut it just fine.  Less than 9V, which is where a 9V battery quickly goes, will not work well.  Also the brightness will quickly diminish significantly. Neither LEDs nor batteries have an equivalent series resistance.  Batteries have IR and LEDs have a Vf.  The Vf is a function of the energy (number of electrons) in the band gap and the number of electrons converted to photons, not a resistance.  LEDs need either a current source or a resistor to allow the LED to float to its Vf

Comment: An LED can, but should never, be connected to a battery without a current limiting resistor.  It is a myth that the battery's IR will do the current limiting.  Look at the IR as a parallel resistance not series.  The IR has no current limiting.   What actually happens with a higher IR button cells is they have low current capabilities but the battery voltage forces the LED to operate at the battery voltage where good design practice dictates the LED to operate at its Vf.  A  resistor is needed to allow the LED to operate at its Vf rather than be stressed to operate at the battery voltage.

Comment: `Current white lighting LEDs typically have a Vf of 2.8V and exceed 3V only at currents approaching 1 Amp.` ***[citation required].***

Comment: Citation required?  How about looking at a datasheet for an LED that was released in the past few years.  Cree XP-3G and XP-L2, OSRAM Oslon Square and Oslon SSL,  Lumiled's Luxeon Rebel Plus and Rebel ES, Luxeon M, Luxeon Z, Luxeon R , Luxeon T.  In mid power Samsung LM301B, Luxeon 3535L HE Plus.   Look at this older 2015 Luxeon M (Fig. 5C) Vf = 2.5V @ 50 mA up to 2.9V @ 4,000 mA.  https://www.lumileds.com/uploads/354/DS103-pdf

Comment: Yeah, cause multi watt leds are what op is using here....

Comment: @Passerby Vf of 2.8 is nominal for good quality 7020's but Rs is quality related and 1/4W LEDs can be 2 to 8 Ohms Ri so Vf can be 3.4 at rated due to quality spread.  8 ohms * 60mA = 480mV rise.  @ misunderstood 4000 mA Vf's are irrelevant due to Rs ( or Internal bulk resistance is inverse to Pd max rating ..., which I won't explain again. Also due to this quality normal variance and cheap online orders, don't *expect* high quality low Rs in LEDs but your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

> The question is not about the intensity of the light that the LEDs can emit, nor about how long the battery will operate.
>   Just, do I need to put a resistance between the battery and the strip.

**No, you do not need to add another resistor, this strip already has a 39Ω resistor.**
[image]

---

With 3 LEDs and a 39Ω Resistor the LEDs will draw about 3-4 mA @ 9V. At this load a 9V alkaline will have a capacity of about 600 mAH as it discharges to 5V.

At 4 mA the forward voltage is likely to be below 9V. So it should be visible for a while.  How long depends on how low the forward voltage can drop before it no longer emits light.

With 3 LEDs and 9V the resistor is going to be very efficient because the forward voltage will be very close to 9V. efficiency will improve as the battery voltage drops.

This strip was intended to draw about 60 mA @ 12V and would likely be fairly bright.  At 3-4 mA not so bright but should be visible.  I would guess brighter than moonlight in a small room.

You can always solder another resistor on top of the existing resistor to draw more current. Any value over 2Ω will work fine.
  2Ω will give you about 50 mA.
  5Ω will give you about 20 mA.
10Ω will give you about 10 mA.
*The above numbers are for a fresh battery.*

Do NOT short the resistor. A resistor is need to allow the LED to operate at its forward voltage. Without a resistor the LED is forced to operate at the battery voltage putting stress on the LED. It is a myth that it's okay to connect an LED(s) directly to a battery.

Below is 3 deep blue LEDs at 10 mA.  Deep blue is what is under the white LED's yellow phosphor. Deep blue light is not very luminous.  After the blue light is absorbed then reemitted by the phosphor it will appear to be about 10x brighter than this blue.

[image]

---

Keep in mind that a 9V battery is 9V for only a very short period of time. 
[image]
Source: [Energizer 9V Alkaline Datasheet](http://data.energizer.com/pdfs/522.pdf)